# Recursively build dictionaries from string characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, recursion

I am working on a compression algorithm for a specific data structure and part of it requires changing a string into a dictionary as follows:

```
    "abc" => {'a':{'b':{'c':{}}}
```

Which is a group of nested dictionaries based on the letters of the word.

How can I do this in a recursive manner in python?

Comment: You probably mean `{'a':{'b':{'c':{}}}`? `{a:{b:{c:{}}}` will raise `NameError`

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake, I have corrected it.

Comment: You stated "recursive" in the question- does that mean you require the solution to use recursion?

Comment: Preferably, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion with list slicing:

```
def to_dict(d):
  return {} if not d else {d[0]:to_dict(d[1:])}

print(to_dict('abc'))
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
s = 'abc'
d = {}
current = d
for c in s:
    current = current.setdefault(c, {})
print(d)
# {'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

seq = 'abc'
result = reduce(lambda value, key: { key : value }, reversed(seq), {})

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}
```